# Pre-order traversal of a non binary tree

Tags: java, preorder

I'm trying to do a pre-order traversal in a non binary tree. The following java code gives me a stack-overflow error at times.

```
private void preorderTraversal(TreeNode node) 
    {
        System.out.println(node);

        if(node.getChildrenCount() == 0)
            return;

        for(Object nextNode: node.getChildren())
        {
            preorderTraversal((TreeNode) nextNode);       // line 113

        }

        return;
    }
```

I can't think of a reason for the error. 
This is the stacktrace;

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at Rule.Tree.preorderTraversal(Tree.java:113)
    at Rule.Tree.preorderTraversal(Tree.java:113)
```

Comment: May have some children who have a parent-relationship to their own parent, possibly.

Comment: Did you mean children with a parent-relationship to themselves?

Comment: What is your definition of a non-binary tree?

Comment: There a more than 2 children for each node.

Comment: @Kon It would be a graph then, and not a tree, right?

Comment: @PriyankGupta Yes, but the poster has not shown the structure he's using to test this method so it's impossible to know.

Comment: @zim did you try to increase a stack size using `java -Xss` option?